# Genererate secret key for cryptography in module

Tags: python, python-2.7, module, cryptography

I have some module, which using AES-128 encryption/decryption. And me necessary automatically generate one time in module secret key (if didnt initialized) for every user, after save and disallow to change. How can I do this?

Comment: Are you asking how to best generate such a key, or how to then store that key and use it from there on out?

Comment: How to store in module. Just once generate, and store all the time.

Comment: I would not store it in the module; you may not even have write access. You can store it in a separate file (one per user, in the user data area for example) would be a much better idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to, you could generate a key and then hard-code the key value using hexadecimals. You could try and hide the value in the code, but it would amount to obfuscation, adding little to no security.

Comment: As explained above, static keys in full view have little to no use.